# Fatal error when i go to admin-> manage category

Tags: magento-1.8

I got this error when i go to "manage category" in admin side.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/shopnow/public_html/errors/report.php'
>   (include_path='/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/local:/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/community:/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/core:/home/shopnow/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home/shopnow/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 925

when i go to error folder, i couldn't found `report.php.`
what should I do to see "manage category" again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally,This issue is solved by myself only. I have Reinstall that extension again which i have uninstalled earlier and the "manage category" page is working again.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about that extension, and you just found the base error based on my answer, so please be respectful with the time i spend to help you and sincere with the community and mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

`[magento_root]/errors/report.php` is a core file, you may loose the file somewhere just download again the magento distribution and copy all files, then (if you are using GIT) check if you are ignoring that file/folder in .gitignore

Comment: After copying report.php from fresh magento distribution,I got this error Source model "Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days" not found for attribute "deal_update_days".I have installed extension named Webinse_DailyDeals.But before few days,i have unistalled that.still this error occured.From where should I delete that attribute ?

Comment: Looks like you'd loose some files are your code under any VCS? According to Magento SE rules you must create another question with the new error and if the report.php file error was solved, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Have you removed the Webinse_DailyDeals extension code? in that case you should write a data-install/upgrade script in order to remove that attribute. if so, please create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION : **

In your database, in table *eav_attribute* remove entries with following attribute_code which were created by webnise:

deals_choice_category

choice_type_dealstime

deal_discount_percent

deal_qty_product_percent

deal_category_id

qty_deal_product

deal_update_days

old_special_date_to

old_special_date_from

old_special_price

deal_statuses

deal_status

deal_bought

deal_qty

deal_end_time

deal_start_time

deal_price

**Run The SQL QUERY** :

DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code in ('deals_choice_category', 'choice_type_dealstime', 'deal_discount_percent', 'deal_qty_product_percent', 'deal_category_id', 'qty_deal_product', 'deal_update_days', 'old_special_date_to', 'old_special_date_from', 'old_special_price', 'deal_statuses', 'deal_status', 'deal_bought', 'deal_qty', 'deal_end_time', 'deal_start_time', 'deal_price');